# How can I use a lambda with captures as a deleter in std::unique_ptr?

Tags: lambda, c++17, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I want to open a file and perform some operation on the file, the `testOpen` and `testClose` are wrappers around the API function `test_open` and `test_close` so that if there's an error in performing these operations I can throw a exception which would help in tracking down the error.

To achieve this I'm using a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter that performs the close operation on the file. Now since I'm not using the API function directly instead a wrapper around the API call, I want to pass the function parameter `std::string const& path` as an argument to the wrapper `testClose(test*, std::string&)`

But I'm not able to pass the `std::string const& path` to the lambda function of the custom deleter parameter of `unique_ptr`.

test is a C library.

This is what I tried.

```
using test_ptr = std::unique_ptr<test, void(*)(test*)>;

test_ptr testOpen(std::string const& path) {
    test_ptr tester(test_open(...), [path](test* t){
        testClose(t, path); // a wrapper around the test_close API function which closes the file at path and might throw an exception if the close operation fails.
    });

    if(!tester) {
        throwTestError(path); // throws an exception
    }

    return test;
}
```

But throws an `error: no matching function for call to 'std::unique_ptr<test, void(\*)(test*)>::unique_ptr(test*, testOpen(std::string const&)::<lambda(test*)>)'`

Also this seems to work fine.

```
using test_ptr = std::unique_ptr<test, void(*)(test*)>;

test_ptr testOpen(std::string const& path) {
    test_ptr tester(test_open(...), [](test* t){
        test_close(t);
    });

    if(!tester) {
        throwTestError(path); // throws an exception
    }

    return test;
}
```

When I don't use the Wrapper `testClose()` instead making the API call directly.

Is there a possible way such that I could use my wrapper `testClose()` instead of making the API call?

Answer (score 0):

A lambda with captures can *never* be used as a function pointer. Only capture-less lambdas can be used for function pointers.

If you have a recent compiler and can build with the C++20 standard, you can use a template type-alias for the `test_ptr` type, and `auto` return type deduction for the function:

```
template<typename F>
using test_ptr = std::unique_ptr<test, F>;

auto testOpen(std::string const& path) {
    test_ptr tester(test_open(), [path](test* t){
        testClose(t, path); // a wrapper around the test_close API function which closes the file at path and might throw an exception if the close operation fails.
    });

    if(!tester) {
        throwTestError(path); // throws an exception
    }

    return tester;
}
```

While this [will build](https://godbolt.org/z/69fsbs6n6), you need to use `auto` and type-deduction everywhere you use the pointer. The type-alias template `test_ptr` is not possible to use for the object returned by `testOpen`. This is a major limiting factor that might prevent its use for your use-case.